# How to render an Link inside MUI data cell

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, hyperlink, datagrid

I tried to render a Link component inside the MUI data-grid cell, my code is as below:

```
import { GridColDef } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const myColumns: GridColDef[] = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70 },        
    {
        field: "prLink",
        headerName: "PR Link",
        width: 150,
        renderCell: (params) => <Link to={params.value} >{params.value}</Link>,
    },
    {
      field: "needExtraCost",
      headerName: "Need E/Cost",
      width: 120,
    },
    ];

    export {
    extraCostColumns
    }
```

And I get error like below:

> ERROR in src/app/models/extra-cost.ts:64:12 TS1005: ';' expected.

It's from the renderCell call, when I remove the line, it's back to normal, I followed the MUI document, is there anything I doing wrong? please advice, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I made a silly mistake that I define these in one of my interface which is ts file, not  tsx and that's why it doesn't recognize the  node.
After I changed to .tsx file and compile again, the error is gone!
Thanks.